# Flag for fixed questions

Tags: support, flags, reopen-closed

After reading the information about flagging posts:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

It seems that it is always used in a negative sense.

Recently I wrote a question that was put on hold because of its low quality. Now that I did some fixes based on the comments, I believe it is good enough to go, and I am very curious to get an answer. However while being closed, it will not be "advertised" for others to decide if it is good enough to be opened again.

What are the hopes for promoting closed questions that have been fixed? Is it acceptable using a flag to request a moderator approval?

Comment: I've already had [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164258/which-framework-does-google-use-for-its-ios-apps) in the reopen queue today and I voted to keep it closed. Seeing your lastest edits I don't see why it is on-topic now. Can you explain why it now fits in [these guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: The question is still 100% off-topic

Comment: Were you aware that editing an on-hold post puts it into the reopen queue? Are you looking for something other than that mechanism, or does the auto-queuing meet your needs?

Comment: I did not know that! After digging deeper I understand better the queue mechanism. My fault, only one link away. Somehow I thought it could only be reopened (and reviewed) by the people closing the question. Since I perceived an emotional reaction to it, I thought I was doomed and my only hope was requesting a moderator. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We prefer you to let the existing re-open queue to get these reopened; that queue gets hit pretty quickly.

If it's been a little while and you just can't generate the interest to get it opened, you can flag, yes. But it's probably going to take a while. As in days, minimum.